# How to automate the installation of Microsoft's critical updates?

Tags: windows, command-line, automatic-update

Is there a way to programmatically configure automatic updates to only install critical updates. I already know about the policy inf file configuration allowed by secedit.exe however nothing speaks specifically about critical updates. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean locally on the machine or for the Domain? WSUS should be able to cover this for your workstations if you have access to a domain controller.....

Comment: This per the local machine.

Answer (score 1):

**Those that are installed automatically *are* critical updates**, the optional have to be done manually.